# R-Tree how to build the bounding boxes to contains road segments

Tags: gis, spatial-index, r-tree

I am new to R-Tree. I want to build a R-Tree for a road network. The road network have road segments (which are lines with source id, segment id, target id). I understand the leaves of an R-Tree are bounding boxes (the rectangles). How can I decide how many segments to put into every bounding box. Another thing is that the road segments are usually connected to each other and I understand for R-Tree, it is better to minimize the overlaps, how to realize this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the bounding box of the road, one road segment at a time.

The R-tree will take care of minimizing the overlap as well as distributing the individual road segments across the leaf nodes. You cannot *avoid* the overlap, unless your roads are disconnected...